# Extend tourist visa stay in USA due to coronavirus and waive I-539 fee

Tags: b1-b2-visas, covid-19, us-visa

My mom has come to US on a tourist visa and her I-94 expires on the first week of May.

Due to the coronavirus, travel restrictions have been imposed in our home country (India). Also we want to avoid the risk of traveling in flights at this time.

Is there an easy way to to extend her stay in the US by one or two months?

I am aware that we should fill out an [I-539](https://www.uscis.gov/i539online) to extend our stay. But in-order to submit the online application it requires a fee of $370.

1. Is filing I-539 the easiest way to extend her stay at this time?
2. If so, is it possible to waive the fee due to the coronavirus
   situation?
3. After filing I-539 should she wait for an approval to continue her
   stay? Or is the receipt good enough?

Can you please help me with these? Thanks!

[Edit 1]: 
With the current situation of the virus, traveling anywhere sounds like a very risky operation, especially for elders.

That is the main reason behind this question. **If the US government will allow visitors to overstay until Covid-19 settles down**!

Comment: There’s no **easy** way to extend her status, there is only one way. I-539. You must be kidding about fee waiver, right. Nobody is going to waive her fee for I-539. In reality the USA government prefers that she leave. A receipt does not mean anything **at all**. My advise for her is to leave **right now**. If her request is denied she will begin to accrue illegal presence after first week of May and her existing visa will be voided if it still has remaining validity.

Comment: Asking for fee waiver **may** imply you’re not in the best financial position. If she falls sick and has to use public services here, in future the public charge rule will be used to deny her a new visa or entry into the USA. The decision is up to you.

Comment: @SyncMaster Even if an extension were possible, no-one knows if ‘one or two months’ would be sufficient. I’m afraid the best (only) option is for your mum to go home to India immediately.

Comment: She likely won't be allowed to go home to India at this point in time. The news has been showing reports about a repatriation flight with Indian citizens from US/Canada being sent back to Schipol airport because India refused them entry.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: India has come to its senses, at least for that particular flight. (Those travelers were stranded at Schiphol, as they couldn't enter the Schengen area.)

Comment: The USA has already deferred Tax Day 3 months, *including the deadline to pay*. (on the one year in the last 20 I owe a tax bill, go me!)  If they'll do that, they'll do *anything*.

Comment: With the current situation of the virus, traveling anywhere sounds like a very risky operation, especially for elders. That is the main reason behind this question. If US government will allow visitors to overstay until Covid-19 settles down.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> Is filing I-539 the easiest way to extend her stay at this time?

Yes.  It's also the hardest way.  It's the only way.

More seriously, there could be some sort of amnesty or other program offered to nonimmigrants in the US who are affected by the pandemic.  If that happens, it could save you a few hundred dollars.

But I wouldn't count on it.  I certainly haven't heard any mention of it, and the current administration is profoundly anti-immigrant, so it's unlikely to happen without political pressure.

In terms of risk analysis, the application fee will be well spent.

> If so, is it possible to waive the fee due to the Corona virus situation?

Applying for a fee waiver is going to make her look like someone with financial problems, which will have a negative impact on her application as well as future applications for admission to the US.  I would not do it.

> After filing I-539 should she wait for an approval to continue her stay? Or is the receipt good enough?

Once the application is filed, she can remain until it is refused, or, if it is granted, until the end of the period of extended stay that is granted.

Comment: This is correct.  I have experience with this.  I think the next step after application is that USCIS will want OP's mom to come in for a "biometrics" appointment.  However, for good reason (virus), USCIS has recently decided to close all "biometrics" centers.  I suspect this will have a positive effect on OP's mom's application.  It will just be on hold until they can schedule a biometrics appointment.  However, who knows what they will do.

Comment: *"she can remain until it is refused"* - To clarify, she can also remain until the original expiry date (if later than the refusal). The way you've phrased it makes it seem like that isn't the case.

Comment: Also, if she is refused and the expiry date has already passed, she must leave _immediately_ which will undoubtedly be significantly more expensive.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy I thought there was a 2 week grace.  She must leave within 2 weeks of the date of rejection.  This page https://forums.immigration.com/threads/i-539-denial.274304/ seems to support that.  BUT IANAL.  However, considering the circumstances I would just overstay no matter what USCIS does.

Comment: @emory That sounds like the denial will indicate the grace period, not that it is specifically or always 2 weeks. But even travel within 2 weeks will normally be significantly more expensive than if you have 3-6 weeks to plan it.

Comment: My main concern is to avoid travel with the current scenario of Covid-19. Flight travel at this time sounds too risky with the exponentially increasing cases day-by-day.

So just having an extension of a month or so will help (hoping the virus situation settles down by then)

Comment: @emory: Is Biometrics mandatory?

Comment: @SyncMaster - the situation is fluid and subject to change but my understanding is that biometrics is mandatory.  However, this probably works to your advantage.  The first thing USCIS will do on receiving your mom's application is try to schedule biometrics.  Since all the biometric offices are closed, this means the application will not even be considered for a long while - not until those guys are comfortable reopening their offices.

Comment: @SyncMaster I feel that a month or two is wildly optimistic.  I would recommend 6 months at the minimum.  The fee is the same whether you apply for a 1 month extension or a 6 month extension, but if you apply for 1 month then I don't know what you would do if things are not OK in 1 month and they are still processing your application.  Can you change your already filed application to add more time?

Comment: @emory I believe 6 months is also the maximum for each extension ([8 CFR 214.2(b)(1)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/214.2#b_1)).

Comment: @phoog I suspect you are right.  That does not change my recommendation at all.  OP should request 6 months because that is both the minimum and maximum.  OP should not want the extension to run out while the virus is still going.

Comment: Hello - I have the same situation with both my parents here with me. We were really hoping situation would improve and they would go back but now there is no hope as it seems. @SyncMaster - Can you please tell me what has happened so far on the application? I am planning to file for extension in next 2-3 days. I read somewhere that I would need a copy of the airline ticket to be submitted but with this situation going on, I don't have a date as yet. How did you handle this? Please help

Comment: Even I m in the same situation, my mother is stranded here. How is the application process going on so far, also regarding biometric how to handle that? @SyncMaster

Comment: Airlift for Indian nationals in the USA Whoever is interested kindly fill this out https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScumxMZ7CdNho-4ZRmjOvdMEVu5oNZn1QsJDiJ_BIQTSC9Itw/viewform

Comment: @cooler I have submitted the online application using https://www.uscis.gov/i539online. They ask for a date until which you want the visa extended. The application is very straightforward and it asks the basic details.