# B2 visa extension due to Covid-19

Tags: b1-b2-visas, covid-19

My mother is currently in the United States on B2 visa and her 1-94 expires on 10-June. Since she has been an asthmatic patient for the last 30 years, I am really worried about her traveling back to India during this covid-19 situation hence I plan to apply for I-539 extension.Some question regarding the same :

1) What are the chances of her extension getting approved given her medical and current covid-19 condition ?

2) If her cases gets denied and leaves united states before her I-94 expires, will her visa still be valid?

3) What happens to her visa status if she leaves the country while her case is still pending and her I-94 has expired ? Do I have to revoke the cases in this situation ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extend Tourist Visa Stay in USA due to Corona Virus and Waive I-539 fee](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/155218/extend-tourist-visa-stay-in-usa-due-to-corona-virus-and-waive-i-539-fee)

Comment: @mlc - Nope. It does not answer my specific questions.

Comment: It answers all of your questions, except the completely unanswerable one: No one can tell what your "chances" are. There are no "chances". If you feel that it doesn't, please be specific as to what your unanswered question is.

Comment: What happens to her visa status if she leaves the country while her case is still pending and her I-94 has expired ? 
Do I have to revoke the case so that it does not get denied ?

Comment: Airlift for Indian nationals in the USA Whoever is interested kindly fill this out https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScumxMZ7CdNho-4ZRmjOvdMEVu5oNZn1QsJDiJ_BIQTSC9Itw/viewform

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/155218/extend-tourist-visa-stay-in-usa-due-to-coronavirus-and-waive-i-539-fee?noredirect=1&lq=1