# Colombian citizen stuck in the US due to coronavirus

Tags: usa, tourist-visas, overstaying, covid-19, colombian-citizens

I was on vacation in the US for 3 weeks. I am a Colombian citizen.

Before I was to return on March 23 to Colombia my flight was cancelled due to Colombia closing its borders including to its citizens that were traveling overseas at the time. All international flights have been canceled.

What happens if my visa travel date expires before I can leave to go to Colombia?

Comment: You might review this Travel.SE question, commnents, and answer: _https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/155218/extend-tourist-visa-stay-in-usa-due-to-corona-virus-and-waive-i-539-fee_

Comment: Contact your embassy and ask about a repatriation flight.

Comment: If you want to read the same answers from the Colombian government itself: here's the consulate in New York on getting in touch with them https://nuevayork.consulado.gov.co/newsroom/news/2020-04-02/22511 and on extending your US visa if necessary https://nuevayork.consulado.gov.co/newsroom/news/2020-03-25/22407 — presumably other consulates in other regions of the country have similar ideas.

Answer (score 5):

You have 3 options.

1. Your US entry could be still valid for a few months. Usually, an entry is valid for 6 months. You can plan to stay in US till situation is clear and flights are open to Colombia. It can be a few months.
2. If your entry is expiring, you can apply for an extension.
3. You can contact your embassy about the possibility of repatriation or any other help. Even if normal flights are not allowed, repatriation with quarantine might be possible.